# django: 360 panoramic photos

Tags: python, django, photo

I'm searching for django 360 panorama app. any suggestions? sample: http://www.0-360.com/ (on the right side).

**UPDATE:** Related questions

[flash/JavaScript: non 360 (partial) panorama viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592458/flash-javascript-non-360-partial-panorama-viewer)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850958/django-flash-with-scrollwheel-fail

Comment: Why is this tagged [Django]?  What part of the Google results were confusing?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it supposed to be django-cms application. Making a infinite loop from 360 photo and scrolling around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of existing Django plugins for viewing 360 pano images.

The page you link to uses the PTViewer java app by Helmut Dersch (see http://www.all-in-one.ee/~dersch/) There are a variety of other viewers available; see http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_Viewers#Flash_or_Shockwave_based_Viewers ; you can try out various viewers at http://www.panoramaphotographer.com/comparisons/

It should not be difficult to create an appropriate Django view; looking at http://360vr.com/2010/01/2010-times-square-midnight-krpflv/index.html for hints:

1. The page has a div in which the player will appear
2. It uses the krpano flash-based player to do the actual display. krpano is very nice, very flexible, and unfortunately not free.
3. It uses javascript to dynamically insert the player code; this allows it to (a) avoid flash-blockers, (b) use an alternative javascript/CSS-based player for display on iPhones, (c) make it really easy to modify later / use the same code for different-sized / dynamically-resizing views. See http://krpano.com/docu/html/

Hope that helps.

Comment: i would like to find jQuerry based plugin. Any suggestions?