# flash/JavaScript: non 360 (partial) panorama viewer

Tags: javascript, flash, plugins, photo, viewer

I'm searching for free partial panorama viewer. It should be placed in  somewhere in the page and it should be customizable (openSource?). So far i found pan0.net but it only supports 360 and i have priority for non 360...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited pan0 sources adding

```
if (camera.rotationY < minRA)
    camera.rotationY = minRA;

if (camera.rotationY > maxRA)
    camera.rotationY = maxRA;
```

to

```
private function calcCameraRotation()
```

and naturally

```
private var minRA: Number = -180;
private var maxRA: Number = 180;
```

by the parameters. And

```
if (loaderInfo.parameters.maxRA)
    maxRA= loaderInfo.parameters.maxRA;

if (loaderInfo.parameters.minRA)
    minRA= loaderInfo.parameters.minRA;
```

to

```
private function processParameters()
```

Sure it makes it non 360 only but few if's and that would be good. But for me it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created one where you can loop an image around horizontal 360 but it does not distort in 3d perspective.
Let me know if that's what you are looking for:
[Web Design Panorama](http://www.bigswordfish.com/v1/forsythpark/)

Comment: it looks nice, yet how it would act when given partial (for e.a. 270 degrees) photo? i need that with given attribute to flash it would stop when encountering side. (simple pan). Currently i'm using pan0.net